# Накладывается друг на другу div элементы

Tags: html, css

Накладываются друг на друга элементы div.
Ниже снимок экрана.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно наименование залазиет на артикул. Ниже Html

```
<div class="name">
                            <?=$produсt->title?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="articul">
                            Артикуль: <?=$produсt->articul?>
                        </div>
```

Так же css:

```
.catalogLine .name{

        margin-top: 14px;
        font-size: 11pt;
        font-weight:bold;
        color: #2f2f2f;
        max-height:48px;
    }



.articul{

    font-size: 8pt;
    font-weight:bold;
    color: #b0b0b0;

}
```

Как сделать так, чтобы блок name не расширялся? Если название длинное, то пусть не показывает

Comment: `overflow: hidden` ?

Comment: Да помогло спасибо! Напишите ответ, приму как правильный

Comment: ну у меня свой вопрос был... именно остальное не показывать или нужно именно если большое название совсем совсем не показывать название? Потому, что тогда немного по-другому будет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если необходимо просто скрыть лишние символы у `title`, то достаточно написать `overflow: hidden` у класса `name`

```
.catalogLine .name{
    margin-top: 14px;
    font-size: 11pt;
    font-weight:bold;
    color: #2f2f2f;
    max-height:48px;

    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Если же нужно совсем не показывать `title` если он длинный, то тогда в `php` уже надо сравнивать длину `title` с нужной длиной и в зависимости от этого выводить его или нет.

К примеру

```
define('TITLE_MAX_LENGTH', 666);

    <div class="name">
        <?php if (strlen($produсt->title) <= TITLE_MAX_LENGTH): ?>
        <?=$produсt->title?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="articul">
        Артикуль: <?=$produсt->articul?>
    </div>
```

Где для кириллицы вместо `strlen` нужно использовать `mb_strlen`

Answer (score 0):

можно добавить `overflow: hidden;` к родительскому блоку, но я бы для большей информативности добавил не только его, но и `text-overflow: ellipsis` - это добавит многоточие в конце, что даст понять клиентам, что текст обрезается из-за большой длины